# tag.class and .class: 2 scenarios

Tags: html, css

### PROBLEM SOLVED. Huge thanks for@JHeth and @Marko Vucurovic. I really appreciate your help!

This question is long but simple
let's look at 2 scenarios:

Scenario I

```
<html>
<head><title>A</title>
<style>
.big {
font-size:300pt}
.small {
font-size:50pt}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="big">
<div class="small"><a href="google.com">Hi</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Since the small class div is the child of the big class div, the font should always be small.
And it turns out in this case font is small (50pt), which makes sense.

If you add div to either .big or .small  in CSS (div.big and div.small), the font is still small.

Scenario II

The interesting part comes when the CSS selector is not ".small" and ".big" but ".small a" and ".big a":

```
<html>
<head><title>A</title>
<style>
.big a{
font-size:300pt}
.small a{
font-size:50pt}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="big">
<div class="small"><a href="google.com">Hi</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Now the font is small, when you add div to both, the font is still small. ***But if you only add div to .big, the font becomes big!***

This has bothered me for 2 days and I registered this forum for it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You didn't close your outer divs properly

Comment: thanks j! i corrected it but the problem still exists!

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. The reason `div.big a` takes precedence over `.small a` is because it has a higher level of specificity you can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and see how the score is calculated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Specificity_2).

Since you only have classes and element selectors in this example the calculation is simple. Classes score 10 points and element selectors score 1 point.

Your selectors would score as follows:

- `div.big a`: 1(div) + 10(.big) + 1(a) = 12
- `.small a`: 10(.small) + 1(a) = 11

Answer (score 0):

It's about CSS selector specificity.

**0 0 0** - fields for id, class, element respectivly

```
div.big a
```

2 elements 1 class so it's : **0 1 2**

```
.small a
```

1 class 1 elemet so it's: **0 1 1**

If you compare these two, you can see that first one is more specific

Comment: Your numbers don't mean anything unless you mention CSS specificity, how it's calculated, and what it means.